# HBase writes getting hanged when multiple threads trying to insert HBase Tables

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hbase, deadlock

I am pretty new in HBase.My application using Kafka Consumers (Which are multithreaded) , which are reading messages from Kafka.Each Consumer read message from Kafka,make puts from message , create HBase Table and perform insertion in HBase.

But guys ,for me ,There is something blocker.This flow is getting hanged after some time.I have attached code for the same , have a look.

```
public void doBatchInsertionForDeviceTable(List<Put> totalRows, Integer hbaseTableSuffix) {
    long start, end;
    HTable tableForDeviceTable = null;
    HBaseConfigurationCache hBaseConfigurationCache = null;
    String tableName = null;
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        hBaseConfigurationCache = CacheManager.getInstance().getCache(HBaseConfigurationCache.class);
        tableName = DataHandlerConstant.HBASE_DEVICE_TABLE + String.valueOf(hbaseTableSuffix);
        tableForDeviceTable = new HTable(hBaseConfigurationCache.getHBaseConfiguration(), tableName);
        LOG.info("Attempting HBase Insertion in Table (" + tableName + ") with rows (" + totalRows.size() + ")");
        try {
            putCountForDeviceStream.addAndGet(totalRows.size());
            LOG.info("Total put have been build till now is :("+putCountForDeviceStream.get()+") for device stream.");
            tableForDeviceTable.put(totalRows);
            LOG.info("Batch have been inserted successfully.");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Problem while inserting rows (" + totalRows.size() + ") ." + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            tableForDeviceTable.flushCommits();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("Sorry,We are unable to perform insertion due to (" + ex.getMessage() + ")");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LOG.info("Consume Time HBase Insertion in Table (" + tableName + ") with rows (" + totalRows.size() + ") is (" + (end - start) + ")");

}
```

Also Thread dump look like this :

> java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)   at
>   sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>     - parking to wait for  <0x00000005adbb0720> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
>     at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread.run(ZkEventThread.java:67)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>     - None
>
> "metrics-meter-tick-thread-2" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fed950c1800
>   nid=0x3006 runnable [0x00007fedb4451000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   TIMED_WAITING (parking)   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>     - parking to wait for  <0x00000005ad4b4608> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>     - None
>
> "metrics-meter-tick-thread-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fed950c8800
>   nid=0x3005 waiting on condition [0x00007fedb4653000]
>   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)     at
>   sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>     - parking to wait for  <0x00000005ad4b4608> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1085)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>     - None
>
> "pool-42-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007fed94b3c800 nid=0x2ffe in
>   Object.wait() [0x00007fedb4955000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForNextTaskDone(AsyncProcess.java:853)
>     - locked <0x00000005af1d9880> (a java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForMaximumCurrentTasks(AsyncProcess.java:879)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitUntilDone(AsyncProcess.java:892)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.backgroundFlushCommits(HTable.java:968)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:1252)
>     at
>   com.snapdeal.datahandler.utils.hbase.HBaseUtils.doBatchInsertionForClickStream(HBaseUtils.java:290)
>     at
>   com.snapdeal.datahandler.hbase.queue.consumer.HBaseWorkerThread.performHBaseInsertion(HBaseWorkerThread.java:111)
>     at
>   com.snapdeal.datahandler.hbase.queue.consumer.HBaseWorkerThread.run(HBaseWorkerThread.java:65)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>     - <0x00000005af1d8260> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
>
> "pool-41-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007fed94b3a800 nid=0x2ffd in
>   Object.wait() [0x00007fedb4a56000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForNextTaskDone(AsyncProcess.java:853)
>     - locked <0x00000005aedcf770> (a java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForMaximumCurrentTasks(AsyncProcess.java:879)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitUntilDone(AsyncProcess.java:892)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.backgroundFlushCommits(HTable.java:968)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:1252)
>     at
>   com.snapdeal.datahandler.utils.hbase.HBaseUtils.doBatchInsertionForClickStream(HBaseUtils.java:290)
>     at
>   com.snapdeal.datahandler.hbase.queue.consumer.HBaseWorkerThread.performHBaseInsertion(HBaseWorkerThread.java:111)
>     at
>   com.snapdeal.datahandler.hbase.queue.consumer.HBaseWorkerThread.run(HBaseWorkerThread.java:65)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>     - <0x00000005aedcf1d8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
>
> "pool-40-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007fed94b38800 nid=0x2ffc in
>   Object.wait() [0x00007fedb4b57000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForNextTaskDone(AsyncProcess.java:853)
>     - locked <0x00000005ad8c8c38> (a java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForMaximumCurrentTasks(AsyncProcess.java:879)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitUntilDone(AsyncProcess.java:892)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.backgroundFlushCommits(HTable.java:968)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:1252)
>     at
>   com.snapdeal.datahandler.utils.hbase.HBaseUtils.doBatchInsertionForClickStream(HBaseUtils.java:290)
>     at
>   com.snapdeal.datahandler.hbase.queue.consumer.HBaseWorkerThread.performHBaseInsertion(HBaseWorkerThread.java:111)
>     at
>   com.snapdeal.datahandler.hbase.queue.consumer.HBaseWorkerThread.run(HBaseWorkerThread.java:65)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>     - <0x00000005ad8c7618> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
>
> "pool-39-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007fed94b36000 nid=0x2ffb in
>   Object.wait() [0x00007fedb4c58000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForNextTaskDone(AsyncProcess.java:853)
>     - locked <0x00000005ad8cf3b8> (a java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForMaximumCurrentTasks(AsyncProcess.java:879)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitUntilDone(AsyncProcess.java:892)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.backgroundFlushCommits(HTable.java:968)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:1252)
>     at
>   com.snapdeal.datahandler.utils.hbase.HBaseUtils.doBatchInsertionForClickStream(HBaseUtils.java:290)
>     at
>   com.snapdeal.datahandler.hbase.queue.consumer.HBaseWorkerThread.performHBaseInsertion(HBaseWorkerThread.java:111)
>     at
>   com.snapdeal.datahandler.hbase.queue.consumer.HBaseWorkerThread.run(HBaseWorkerThread.java:65)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

Comment: Anybody,Please help me ?

Comment: were you able to resolve?